# Multiple JAXB objects generated when converting XSD to Java

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to use Spring with JAXB to convert an XSD/XML file to java JAXB objects
The schema i am working with has fields as shown below:

```
<simpleType name="productType">
 <restriction base="string"/>
</simpleType>   

<complexType name="child">
 <sequence>
   <element name="product" type="productType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </sequence>       
</complexType>

<element name="products">
 <complexType>
   <sequence>
     <element ref="child"/>
   </sequence>
 </complexType>
</element>
```

When JAXB works with the above schema it generates two classes:

```
Products.java
Child.java
```

Whith "Child" being an object inside the Products class as a list:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<Child> child;
```

This is fine when converting an XML/XSD file to a JAXB object but when doing the conversion the other way round, i.e. converting a Hibernate or just a simple javabean to the JaxB object, it is very difficult to map the fields. In the above example, i have to first create the "Child" objects, put them in a list then create the "Product" Object.

It seems like JAXB generates a class for each type i define in the XSD file.

You can imagine how confusing this can get for a very large xml file with several level inner tags. Is it possible to generate a single JAXB object regardless of how many levels are in the xml file? (i.e. not create a separate class for each type defined in the XSD file.)

Comment: That doesn't sound like a great design to me. How would you deal with repeating groups that way? The way JAXB works is pretty readable, you may hit some impedance converting between JPA and JAXB entities, but this is quite common.

Comment: Do you mean the design of the schema itself is the problem? If i change the schema to use the "Russian "Doll" approach (as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819377/validating-an-xml-file-using-xsd-schema-files-xml-structure) then it generates a single java class but i have been advised not to use that approach.

Comment: I mean, why do you only want one class file? Also, could you try a simple JAXB mapping from your JPA entity and capture that as your schema?

Comment: I didn't know that was possible but will investigate it to find out how that is done.

Comment: The JaxB object will end up as one class. I want to be able to have a one to one mapping between the JaxB and the JPA object. Without the one 2 one mapping, i have to generate several other child objects for the inner tags because i declared them as types in the schema.